# BSTs with repeating keys

Tags: trees, combinatorics, binary-trees, search-trees, counting

The problem is to count number of unique binary search trees with keys $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$, given that some of the keys are not unique. For example, $a$ could be 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4.

We could try an approach that is similar to the case when keys are unique - choose some root node from $a$ and then solve two subproblems - one on the prefix before the root and, similarly, on the suffix after the root. Then we sum over all chosen roots and multiply prefix and suffix subproblem answers. For the example above, there are six prefix subproblems:

- 1 (answer is 1)
- 1, 1 (answer is 1)
- 1, 1, 2 (answer is 3)
- 1, 1, 2, 3 (???)
- 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 (???)
- 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 (???)

The answers are obvious in case when prefix contains just [1, 1, ..., 1] or [1, 1, .., 1, 2], but how can we solve next ones?

Answer (score 0):

Any tree structure can be labeled with keys to make a BST. This property does not need for the keys to be different.

That means that there are as many BST over $n$ keys (some not unique) as there are binary trees over $n$ nodes: the $n$-th Catalan number, $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.